# displaying featured image url of custom post type in image tag

Tags: custom-post-types

I have two custom post types in my theme. I want to display the featured image as background image. How can I do that

```
    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post-slug'
            );
            $query = new WP_Query($args);
             $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');
        ?>
        <?php if($query -> have_posts()): while($query -> have_posts()): $query -> the_post(); ?>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">    
                    <div class="col-sm-5 content-img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>');">
                        <img src="<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>" alt="" class="visible-sm visible-xs">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-5 content-detail">
                        <div class="team-content-wrapper wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1500ms" data-wow-delay="1000ms">
                            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div> <!-- team content wrapper end -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
```

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `get_the_post_thumbnail($post, $size, $attrs)/the_post_thumbnail($post, $size, $attrs)` for print image full taq or `get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post, $size, $attrs)` if you want return just featured image url.

Also you can use `wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, $size, $atts)` or `wp_get_attachment_image_url($attachment_id, $size, $atts)` for not featured images but from your media library.